# Possible to extend two lists at once?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists (list_1,list_2) and a function which returns two lists (list_1_f, list_2_f) and I would like to add the items of list_1_f to list_1 and the items of list_2_f to list_2:

```
def lists():
    list_1_f = [10,10,10]
    list_2_f = [20,20,20]    
    return list_1_f,list_2_f

list_1, list_2 = [1,1,1], [2,2,2]
```

The case is that I always have 2 original lists and the extension is going to be done just for another two extra lists. So that at the end I would have two lists with the original items plus the ones got from the function, and the output would be:

```
list_1 = [1,1,1,10,10,10]
list_2 = [2,2,2,20,20,20]
```

I have tried the following lines using extend function but none works:

```
list_1.extend([]), list_2.extend([]) = lists()
list_1.extend(), list_2.extend() = lists()
list_1.extend, list_2.extend = lists()
```

I could always do the following:

```
list_1a, list_2a = lists()
list_1.extend(list_1a)
list_2.extend(list_2a)
```

But I was wondering if it is even possible to make the extension without having to create two intermediate lists.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by extend?  Like add a 4th (1) to the first list, and a 4th (2) to the second one?  If you could clarify exactly what you want the code to do, it'd be easier to help you.

Comment: Do you want to extend both lists with the same elements, or different elements, please be more clear

Comment: I think OP just wants a flat list as a result from calling the function?

Comment: Could you give some feedback Javier? It is obviously quite unclear what you're asking

Comment: Not quite sure anyways why you would define a function to generate lists... You should be more clear.. voting to close

Comment: mean this: `my_list = [item for sublist in lists() for item in sublist]` ?

Comment: If you really feel you have to do this it's a good sign that your design is off somewhere, in other words you have an XY problem. Consider refactoring some of the code so that what you want to do becomes straightforward in python.

Comment: I have edited the question, I hope it is more clear now. @yatu Well, this is a simplified version of the problem, my real case is a function inside a class which populates two lists after several processes. I guess that I could access to those lists inside the class without returning anything anyway

Comment: Okay makes more sense now @JavierLópezTomás perhaps you could ask again as I have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not directly possible, because what must be on the left side of an assignment cannot be a function call. It can only be built from simple variables, data members, subscripts and commas, parentheses or square brackets.

Best that can be done is to use a comprehension or a map on the right side:

```
list_1, list_2 = map(lambda x: sum(x, []), zip((list_1, list_2), lists()))
```

(thanks to @meowgoesthedog for that way)

Whether it is better that a clear code using 3 lines is up to the reader. IMHO the only real use case would be inside a lambda which only supports a unique expression

Comment: I think it's probably better to avoid calling `lists()` twice, and do something like `*map(sum, zip((list_1, list_2), list()))`.

Comment: Let's all agree that this is ugly as sin and not in any way better than the OP's code.

Comment: `sum(x, [])` is a horribly inefficient antipattern