# Extending two lists at once

Tags: python, list

I have two lists (list_1,list_2) and a function which returns two lists (list_1_f, list_2_f) and I would like to add the items of list_1_f to list_1 and the items of list_2_f to list_2:

```
def lists():
    list_1_f = [10,10,10]
    list_2_f = [20,20,20]    
    return list_1_f,list_2_f

list_1, list_2 = [1,1,1], [2,2,2]
```

I always will have 2 original lists and the extension is going to be done just for another two extra lists, there is no other possibility. So that at the end I would have two lists with the original items plus the ones got from the function, and the output would be:

```
list_1 = [1,1,1,10,10,10]
list_2 = [2,2,2,20,20,20]
```

I have tried the following lines using extend function but none works:

```
list_1.extend([]), list_2.extend([]) = lists()
list_1.extend(), list_2.extend() = lists()
list_1.extend, list_2.extend = lists()
```

I could always do the following:

```
list_1a, list_2a = lists()
list_1.extend(list_1a)
list_2.extend(list_2a)
```

But I was wondering if it is even possible to make the extension without having to create two intermediate lists.

Comment: You're not "creating" two lists in the middle, they already are there in the memory, you're just giving them names. ;) I don't think there's a simple option to do that because `= lists()` is assigning this value to the name(s) before `=`, but you don't want the assignment, you want to pass the value to a method.

Comment: This should not be set as a dupe of the previously asked question by OP, which was closed as initially unclear. The question has been since modified and seems more clear now. So reopening

Comment: @yatu it's an exact duplicate!

Comment: Yes @AndrasDeak the question from that dupe was modified after being closed. It initially was unclear. Thats why it was closed. The updated and *clearer*  version from that post is the same as this one, but as it was not getting reopened OP decided to go ahead and ask again?

Comment: @yatu the other question was closed as unclear so this one is not a dupe? You've lost me.

Comment: No @andras It was closed for being unclear, but modified *after* being closed. But as it was no longer possible to answer I'm guessing OP just went ahead and posted the same *updated* question

Comment: The dupe was edited 24 minutes ago, this was asked 10 minutes ago. Dupe from the start, @yatu. But whatever.

Comment: Oh you actually [told the OP to reask the question to answer it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491162/possible-to-extend-two-lists-at-once#comment99573789_56491162)! Very smooth, @yatu, also explains everything.

Comment: The dupe has no good answers anyway @AndrasDeak why not just let this open given that people are making an effort to answer?

Comment: Yes @AndrasDeak why not? Couldn't answer that post anyways..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For handling multiple lists you should be using nested lists instead.  Say for instance you initially have this nested list:

```
l =  [[1,1,1], [2,2,2]]
```

You could [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) both nested lists and use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to extend the returned sublists using [`operator.add`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) :

```
from operator import add

extended_list = *map(add, *zip(l, lists())),
# ([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [10, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate, so you could do something like:

```
list_1.extend(lists()[0])
list_2.extend(lists()[1])
```

This works but is not very readable. If you make a list of lists you want to append to`list_of_lists=[list_1,list_2]` then you can do the following:

```
for n in list_of_lists:
  list_of_lists[n].extend(lists()[n])
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend one list with another with just summarizing them:

`[1,2,3] + [4,5,6]`

> `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

So your code may looks like this:

```
def lists():
    list_1_f = [10,10,10]
    list_2_f = [20,20,20]    
    return list_1_f,list_2_f

list1 = [0]
list2 = [999]

list1 = list1 + lists()[0]
list2 = list2 + lists()[1]

print(list1, list2)
```

> `[0, 10, 10, 10] [999, 20, 20, 20]`